# Nested loop over indices when creating a dict value that is itself a dict

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, nested-loops

I'm looping through a list of lists to create a dictionary of dictionaries where the keys are unique ints and the values are dictionaries containing contact information. The first list within the list of lists are the keys for the nested dictionary. Is there a way to nested loop this rather than typing out all of the indices? This would get hard if there were a bunch more columns of information.

```
all_employees_dict = {}
for index, each in enumerate(all_employees[1:]):
    all_employees_dict[index] = {
                                all_employees[0][0]:each[0], 
                                all_employees[0][1]:each[1],
                                all_employees[0][2]:each[2],
                                all_employees[0][3]:each[3],
                                all_employees[0][4]:each[4],
                                }
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, with a list comprehension:

```
all_employees_dict = {}
for index, each in enumerate(all_employees[1:]):
    all_employees_dict[index] = {all_employees[0][j]:each_val for j, each_val in enumerate(each)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map a list of (key,value) pairs to a dict like this:

```
>>> print dict([(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')])
{1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
```

Given that, you can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up the keys from the first list with values from the rest of the lists:

```
employee_keys = all_employees[0]
result = {}
for index, employee_values in enumerate(all_employees[1:]):
  result[index] = dict(zip(employee_keys, employee_values))
```

To create it using a cool generator expression, you can do this, which creates an iterable giving each employee's dict using the same technique as before, then relies on the fact that `enumerate` creates (index, value) pairs which `dict` can then consume.

```
employee_keys = all_employees[0]
result = dict(
  enumerate(
    dict(zip(employee_keys, employee_values))
    for employee_values in all_employees[1:]
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point to make a dictionary based on indices that are similar to what you get with a list [0, 1, 2, 3...]. So:

```
all_employees_dict = {}
for index, each in enumerate(all_employees[1:]):
    all_employees_dict[index] = {
                                all_employees[0][0]:each[0], 
                                all_employees[0][1]:each[1],
                                all_employees[0][2]:each[2],
                                all_employees[0][3]:each[3],
                                all_employees[0][4]:each[4],
                                }
```

Is **probably** just like:

```
all_employees_dict = [{k: v for k, v in zip(all_employees[0], employee)} for employee in all_employees[1:]]
```

But you get a `list` you can access using it's indices rather than a `dict` with keys.